# foo in bar - 'in' operator javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I recently read a tutorial on CSS browser feature detection... The end product was something like this...

```
var prefix = ['Moz', 'webkit', 'O', 'ms', 'Khtml'],
    test_style = document.createElement('div').style;

var css_check = function(prop) {
    if (prop in test_style) {
        return true;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < prefix.length; i++) {
        if (prefix[i] + prop in test_style) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

css_check('whatev_css_property');
```

The part I dont understand is this...

`if (prop in test_style)` or `if (foo in bar)`.

From what I've read `if (foo in bar)` is used to check if a value is in an array but I might be wrong here, I haven't found much documentation on this. Also, if this is used to check values in an array HOW is `test_style = document.createElement('div').style` an array? Doesn't make sense...

I am terrible confused. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using `foo in bar` to check for the presence of a value in arrays - you should use `indexOf` ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript ). In your case, `test_style` is an object literal, in which case `foo in bar` is correct for checking for a key's presence. Using `foo in bar` checks for the presence of an index being filled in an array (where the index is like the same as an object's key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` operator is used to check for the presence of a *key* in an array or object, e.g.

```
3 in [1, 2, 3] // false, since the array indices only go up to 2
2 in [1, 2, 3] // true
'x' in { x: 5 } // true
'toString' in Object.prototype // true
```

The `style` property there is an instance of [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration), which contains properties for each supported style attribute in the active browser.

The code snippet you gave in your post checks whether the viewing browser supports some version of that style (either the official one or with one of a number of common vendor prefixes).

Comment: Thanks for the examples. makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

The statement `if (foo in bar)` tests whether the object `bar` has a property *named* `foo`. It doesn't test for a property with the value `foo`.

That is:

```
var bar = {"a" : "x", "b" : "y"};
alert("a" in bar); // true
alert("x" in bar); // false
```

You can use this syntax on arrays because they are a type of object. If `bar` is an array then `foo in bar` will be true if `foo` is either a numeric index of the array that has a value or if `foo` is some other property or method name.

> Also, if this is used to check values in an array HOW is `test_style = document.createElement('div').style` an array?

`test_style` is an object, not an array.

Comment: I think `hasOwnProperty` applies to this too. If you only want to check if an index exists, you could use `if ("1" in array && array.hasOwnProperty("1"))` - in the case that the thing being checked is dynamic and not hardcoded as `"1"`. This way, it ignores any native methods. Right? Just wondering

Comment: @ianpgall - If you're using `.hasOwnProperty()` (which I probably should've mentioned in my answer) you don't need the `in` operator as well.

Comment: Oh yeah, good point, that was silly to keep. Well, there's a lot that could be discussed on these things, the difference between arrays/objects and how to access them, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
 document.createElement('div').style
```

will return a object which have CSS properties. you can use `key in` to check if particular property  exist in a object.

Answer (score 1):

`if (foo in bar)` is used to check whether the value named `foo` is a property of the object `bar`. Since arrays are just specially treated objects, you are correct in assuming that it can be used to check for a value in an array.

`test_style = document.createElement('div').style` returns an object with properties; since this is the case, you can use the `foo in bar` syntax to check it.

Comment: _"you are correct in assuming that it can be used to check for a value in an array."_ - it doesn't check for a _value,_ it checks for a property _name_ (or, in an array, whether a specific _index_ has a value).

Comment: Using `foo in bar` with an array will not work. You're right that it's like an object, but in an array, it's "keys" will be the indices. So using `foo in bar` will check for an index existing.